# Should I worry about TTFB?

Tags: apache-2.4, centos7, vps, optimization

I have read differing opinions on the subject, but Im also wondering how much of this is affected by server location.

I have a VPS in NY, USA and im an Australian developer, VPS' are pretty pricey where I live so I use this as a playground/self hosting for dev etc.

[image]

I am in the process of ensuring I can optomize everything possible in my Centos 7 apache + nginx server.

But this is very concering, as I believe ping should only be around 180ms to 300ms delay, not 1 second+

What, if anything, can I do?

Comment: What is the TTFB for a static resource like an image?

Comment: Also, what is the actual ping time?  TTFB in chrome debugger includes all server side processing not just network round trip.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/yL1d11b.png My main site is currently on nginx, running a wordpress CMS with several plugins and custom theme, that image is about 200kb

Comment: Also the actual ping time according to pingdom from NY USA to my server is 316ms which seems slow considering how close that is to my server